# Simulating Small Differential Drive Robot in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, velocity, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to simulate a small 4WD differential drive robot in Gazebo. I am using the erratic_gazebo_plugin diffdrive_plugin controller which I modified to work with a 4WD system.

My simulation works fine when I use the erratic's wheel diameter of .15 m. But when I change the diameter to .1 m for my wheels the odometry published claims the robot is moving at .7 m/s despite me commanding 1 m/s in the Twist msg.

I am using a moment of inertia of `ixx = 0.01 ;ixy = 0 ; ixz = 0 ; iyy= .01 ; iyz = 0 ; izz = .01`.

My wheel mass is `.1 kg`

I think my issue has to do with the `mu1, mu2, kp, and kd` parameters currently I have them set at `mu1 = 200 ; mu2 = 100 ; kp = 1000000 ; and kd = 1`.

I guess my issue is I am unclear how these parameters are used in the simulator as well as what is the effect decreasing the wheel diameter. I can trick the simulator by decreasing my wheel diameter in the controller's parameters but I would like to understand why this phenomenon occurs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47612/simulating-small-differential-drive-robot-in-gazebo/) by [malvarado](https://answers.ros.org/users/3532/malvarado/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-11-06**:
@Malvarado Gazebo has a known issue with very low moments of inertia

**Comment by [malvarado](https://answers.ros.org/users/3532/malvarado/) on 2012-11-07**:
I am using the moment of inertia values that are used in the erratic URDF. What do you recommend I increase them to?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-02-01**:
was this concern ever resolved?

**Comment by [malvarado](https://answers.ros.org/users/3532/malvarado/) on 2013-03-07**:
No this was never resolved

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-02-03**:
hey, im trying to add differential drive to my custom robot but dont know how. Can you give me any instructions please? I have my robot urdf file from solidworks already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try changing the odometrySource parameter of your differential drive plugin from world to encoder.

This fixed it for me.

Edit: This actually breaks the linear velocity you get from odom.
See also: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/327

---

Originally posted by [AReimann](https://answers.ros.org/users/20356/areimann/) with karma: 88 on 2015-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1